# What's the best way to reference to a mapped input in React?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to reference to an input value rendered by a map(), but quickly found out that document.getElementById is not the way to go. I think using useRef is difficult because of the mapping.
What is the most efficient and effective method for referencing a mapped input in a React application? Are there any specific techniques or tools that are particularly useful for this task?

```js
import { Fragment, useContext } from "react";
import { RoutineContext } from "../../context/CurrentRoutineContext";


export default function Card() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const { currentRoutine } = useContext(RoutineContext);

  return (
    <>
      {currentRoutine.sections.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.name} className="w-full rounded-md sm:max-w-md sm:shadow-lg">
            {/* Header */}
            <div className="px-4 py-5 border-b border-gray-200 shadow-md bg-gravel-400 sm:px-6">
              <h3 className="text-xl font-medium leading-6 text-center text-slate-100">
                {item.name}
              </h3>
            </div>
            {/* Body */}
            <div className="p-3">
              {item.exercises.map((item, idx) => (
                <div key={item.name} className="px-2 py-1.5">
                  <span className="block font-semibold text-gravel-700">{item.name}</span>
                  <table className="min-w-full">
                    <thead>
                      <tr key={item.name}>
                      //Table headers....
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200">
                      <tr key={item.name} className="w-full py-1">
                        <td className="px-2 text-sm text-gray-500 whitespace-nowrap">
                          {/* I want this input's value */}
                          <input
                            type="number"
                            className="w-12 pl-1 text-base rounded-sm bg-gravel-100"
                          />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <button
                            disabled={false}
                            onClick={() => {}}
                            type="button"
                          >
                            <CheckIcon className="w-5 h-5 p-1 text-center text-stone-800" />
                          </button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have the ref itself be a map then use the callback form of the `ref` prop to populate it.

```
import { Fragment, useContext } from "react";
import { RoutineContext } from "../../context/CurrentRoutineContext";


export default function Card() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const { currentRoutine } = useContext(RoutineContext);
  const fields = useRef({})

  return (
    <>
      {currentRoutine.sections.map((section) => (
          <div key={section.name} className="w-full rounded-md sm:max-w-md sm:shadow-lg">
            {/* Header */}
            <div className="px-4 py-5 border-b border-gray-200 shadow-md bg-gravel-400 sm:px-6">
              <h3 className="text-xl font-medium leading-6 text-center text-slate-100">
                {section.name}
              </h3>
            </div>
            {/* Body */}
            <div className="p-3">
              {item.exercises.map((exercise, idx) => (
                <div key={exercise.name} className="px-2 py-1.5">
                  <span className="block font-semibold text-gravel-700">{exercise.name}</span>
                  <table className="min-w-full">
                    <thead>
                      <tr key={exercise.name}>
                      //Table headers....
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody className="divide-y divide-gray-200">
                      <tr key={exercise.name} className="w-full py-1">
                        <td className="px-2 text-sm text-gray-500 whitespace-nowrap">
                          {/* I want this input's value */}
                          <input
                            type="number"
                            className="w-12 pl-1 text-base rounded-sm bg-gravel-100"
                            ref={(el) => {
                              if (!fields.current[section.id]) fields.current[section.id] = {}
                              fields.current[section.id][exercise.id] = el
                            }
                          />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                          <button
                            disabled={false}
                            onClick={() => {}}
                            type="button"
                          >
                            <CheckIcon className="w-5 h-5 p-1 text-center text-stone-800" />
                          </button>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

Now `fields.current` will have a structure like:

```
{
  "section_id_123": {
     "exercise_id_123": // <-- HTML ELEMENT HERE
     // Other exercises in this section
  }
  // Other sections
}
```

I made an assumption both `section` and `exercise` have an `id` property. You could probably use `name` if uniqueness is guaranteed.

**However** this is usually where you are at the point where you have reached the practical limits of "uncontrolled" forms. At this point you should look into changing your form to be "[controlled](https://beta.reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state#recommendation-fully-controlled-component)". It would be much easier to manage.

You might consider using a form lib also.

Comment: Please check this again as I originally forgot to use `fields.current` instead of just `fields`.

Comment: See also https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: Would I reference the value with section_id_1.exercise_id_1.current.value?

Comment: References as `fields.current[sectionid][exerciseid]` where `sectionid` and `exerciseid` are replaced with the actual string values inside of `exercise.id` and `section.id` for that item. As mentioned in answer, the answer assumes those objects have unique `id` properties. You can change the code to use `name` but generally speaking you want an id property as uniqueness is guaranteed.